# The difference between PRINT @@ROWCOUNT and OUTPUT $ACTION in sql server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Apologies if my question seems to be naive:
I cannot get my head around the 2 statements below, can someone please explain the difference:

```
OUTPUT $ACTION, INSERTED.BuildRequestID, ..... and
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Apparently, they both can be used to print something on the window, with output in the example above, the records that have been inserted will be displayed. And, PRINT @@ROWCOUNT returns the number of rows affected by the last executed statement in the batch, so, if the function was insert, then it will show the inserted records?

Thank you,

Comment: There is nothing in common between these two lines, so it is difficult to tell how they are different. They are absolutely different and not related.

Comment: @GSerg, can you please explain the difference in 2 use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its simplest terms, [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will give you the actual records affected by a DML statement (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE), [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will just tell you how many rows were affected by the previous Statement (not limited to DML).

This is probably easiest understood with a working example that you can run yourself and see both in action:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

-- CHECK @@ROWCOUNT
DECLARE @RowCountFromDropTable INT = @@ROWCOUNT;

-- CREATE A TABLE
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Col CHAR(1) NOT NULL);

-- INSERT SOME VALUES AND CHECK THE OUTPUT
INSERT #T (ID, Col) 
OUTPUT inserted.*
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C');

-- CHECK @@ROWCOUNT
DECLARE @RowCountFromInsert INT = @@ROWCOUNT;

-- DELETE A VALUE AND INSPECT THE DELETED RECORD WITH OUTPUT
DELETE  #T
OUTPUT deleted.*
WHERE   ID = 3;

-- CHECK @@ROWCOUNT
DECLARE @RowCountFromDelete INT = @@ROWCOUNT;

-- UPDATE A RECORD AND VIEW BEFORE AND AFTER VALUES
UPDATE  #T
SET     Col = 'X'
OUTPUT inserted.ID AS ID, 
        inserted.Col AS UpdatedTo, 
        deleted.Col AS UpdatedFrom
WHERE   ID = 2;

-- CHECK @@ROWCOUNT
DECLARE @RowCountFromUpdate INT = @@ROWCOUNT;

-- USE MERGE, AND CAPTURE ACTION:
MERGE #T AS t
USING (VALUES (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')) AS s (ID, Col)
    ON s.ID = t.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, Col) VALUES (s.ID, s.Col)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Col = s.Col
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
    OUTPUT $Action AS DMLAction, 
            inserted.ID AS InsertedID, 
            inserted.Col AS InsertedCol, 
            deleted.ID AS DeletedID, 
            deleted.Col AS DeletedCol;

-- CHECK @@ROWCOUNT
DECLARE @RowCountFromMerge INT = @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT  RowCountFromDropTable = @RowCountFromDropTable,
        RowCountFromInsert = @RowCountFromInsert,
        RowCountFromDelete = @RowCountFromDelete,
        RowCountFromUpdate = @RowCountFromUpdate,
        RowCountFromMerge = @RowCountFromMerge;
```

The recordsets output from each of the DML are:

**INSERT**

```
ID  Col
-------
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

**DELETE**

```
ID  Col
-------
3   C
```

**UPDATE**

```
ID  UpdatedTo   UpdatedFrom
---------------------------
2       X           B
```

**MERGE**

```
DMLAction   InsertedID  InsertedCol DeletedID   DeletedCol
------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT          3           C           NULL        NULL
DELETE          NULL        NULL        1           A
UPDATE          2           B           2           X
```

**INSPECT @@ROWCOUNTS**

```
RowCountFromDropTable   RowCountFromInsert  RowCountFromUpdate  RowCountFromMerge
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        0                       3                   1                   3
```

A quick point on some wording in the qeustion too: You cannot use `OUTPUT` directly to print something to the window, it returns records much like a `SELECT` statement. `@@ROWCOUNT` can be used like any scalar function, so you *could* use this in consecutive statements. So you could do something like this:

```
SELECT  TOP (1) *
FROM    (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS t (ID);

SELECT  TOP (@@ROWCOUNT + 1) *
FROM    (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS t (ID);

SELECT  TOP (@@ROWCOUNT + 1) *
FROM    (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS t (ID);
```

Which returns `1`, `1,2` and `1,2,3` respectively. I have no idea why you would want to do this, but it demonstrates the scope of `@@ROWCOUNT` a bit better than the above, and how it *can* be used elsewhere.

Comment: I do appreciate your time

Comment: Just to round out this exceptionally thorough answer, the `$ACTION` syntax you inquired about only applies to `MERGE` statements, and is detailed in the documentation for the `OUTPUT` clause that Gareth has already pointed you towards.